# How to display list of data in a column in iview table

Tags: vue.js, iview

In iview table, my colums：

```
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        columns5: [
          {
            title: 'CNAME',
            key: 'name',
            sortable: true
          },
          {
            title: 'nodes',
            key: 'nodes',
          },
          {
            title: 'domains',
            key: 'domains',
          },
          {
            title: 'desc',
            key: 'desc'
          },
          {
            title: 'duetime',
            key: 'duetime',
            sortable: true
          },
          {
            title: 'ctime',
            key: 'ctime',
            sortable: true
          },
          {
            title: 'uptime',
            key: 'uptime',
            sortable: true
          },
        ],
```

the data:

```
  anames:[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "nodes": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "main_ip": "10.10.10.10",
                "ips": "10.10.10.10\r\n10.10.10.11",
                "req_secret": null,
                "ctime": "2021-05-17T09:41:53.159131+08:00",
                "uptime": "2021-05-17T10:31:47.886033+08:00",
                "cname": 1
            }
        ],
        "domains": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "domain_name": "baidu.com",
                "ctime": "2021-05-17T16:19:18.097807+08:00",
                "uptime": "2021-05-17T16:19:18.097955+08:00",
                "cname": 1
            }
        ],
        "name": "masdcom",
        "desc": "",
        "desc_en": null,
        "is_active": true,
        "duetime": "2021-06-17T19:40:00+08:00",
        "ctime": "2021-05-17T09:13:57.019125+08:00",
        "uptime": "2021-05-17T19:42:23.025122+08:00",
        "user": 2
    }
]
```

You see my nodes and domains，in data `anames` they are list, not just key-value, how can I display domain's domain_name and node's main_ip?

In there can not use `domains.domain_name` and `nodes.main_ip`.

[image]

I want nodes display all node's main_ip  and domains display all domain's domain_name. what should I do in columns?

Answer (score 0):

domains and nodes is array, you forgot about indexes

`domains[0].domain_name` and `nodes[0].main_ip`